# can't connect to 587

Tags: postfix-mta

When I run

```
telnet localhost 587
```

There's error:

```
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

But why I can connect to localhost 25?

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

I'm using postfix as my SMTP server.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you configure your server to listen on port 587?

Comment: gotcha, 587      inet  n     -     n     -     -     smtpd under file master.cf

Comment: yup, that was me too, thanks david schwartz

Comment: @david, can you please put in a new answer so Yuming can mark as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you configure your server to listen on port 587?